# I was using flask to make a project while importing flask I'm getting this Error and I don't Know what does it mean

Tags: python, flask

Error:
(venv) PS D:\Nxt\backend> python server.py
C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonuch .exe: can't open file 'D:\Nxt\backend\server.py': [Errno 2]
No such file or directory
(venv) PS D:\Nxt\backend>

```js
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


# Members API
@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return {"members": ["Member1", "Member2", "Member3"]}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And on debugging python file I am getting Error in terminal:-

Code
PS D:\Nxt> python -u "d:\Nxt\backend\venv\server.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Nxt\backend\venv\server.py", line 1, in 
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
PS D:\Nxt>

Python Debug Console

PS D:\Nxt>  & 'C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Hello.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\ler' 'auncher' '55093' '--' 'd:\Nxt\backend\venv\server.py'

Comment: Do you have ```flask``` in your ```requirements.txt``` file? Did you install the contents of that file before running your program?

Comment: yes you're right in requiremnts.txt , flask was not present. But after installing again it is showing AGAIN SAME ERROR D:\Nxt\backend> python server.py
C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\Nxt\ba\server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:

Comment: List the contents of your requirements.txt file. Also show your project directory structure

Comment: thanks @NoCommandLine I did not runned    >$env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
> flask run   Ref- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/      https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/installation/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment but if you have sorted out your issues, then good. If not, please explain your last comment

Comment: Yes it is sorted.